# postgres using knex/bookshelf relational query

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

The bootcamp I went to taught postgres using the knex/bookshelf libraries, but at the moment I don't know how to use the reqular queries(ie. SELECT FROM etc...).
I've haven't  tried a relational query with the knex/bookshelf libraries until now and I can't get it to work.  I've looked at the documentation and as far as I can tell I've used the syntax they say to.

```
      exports.getStudentsByClass = (key) => {
         return Classroom.where({ id: key }).fetch({
        withRelated: 'student'
        })
        .then(classroom => {
              const students = classroom.related('student')
              console.log(classroom.models.map(student => {
                    studentList.attributes
              }))
              return classroom
        })
        .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
        })
       }
```

This is the function I am using to query the database.  When I console log the data this is what I get

```
CollectionBase {
 model:
{ [Function]
 super_: [Function: Events],
 extend: [Function: extend],
 extended: [Function: extended],
 __super__:
  ModelBase {
    _builder: [Function: builderFn],
    _relation: [Function: _relation],
    Collection: [Object] },
 NotFoundError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
 NoRowsUpdatedError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
 NoRowsDeletedError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
 forge: [Function: forge],
 collection: [Function: collection],
 count: [Function: count],
 fetchAll: [Function: fetchAll],
 where: [Function],
 query: [Function] },
length: 5,
models:
[ ModelBase {
   attributes: [Object],
   _previousAttributes: [Object],
   changed: {},
   relations: {},
   cid: 'c77',
   id: 7 },
 ModelBase {
   attributes: [Object],
   _previousAttributes: [Object],
   changed: {},
   relations: {},
   cid: 'c78',
   id: 4 },
 ModelBase {
   attributes: [Object],
   _previousAttributes: [Object],
   changed: {},
   relations: {},
   cid: 'c79',
   id: 9 },
 ModelBase {
   attributes: [Object],
   _previousAttributes: [Object],
   changed: {},
   relations: {},
   cid: 'c80',
   id: 14 },
 ModelBase {
   attributes: [Object],
   _previousAttributes: [Object],
   changed: {},
   relations: {},
   cid: 'c81',
   id: 10 } ],
 _byId:
  { '4':
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c78',
    id: 4 },
 '7':
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c77',
    id: 7 },
 '9':
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c79',
    id: 9 },
 '10':
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c81',
    id: 10 },
 '14':
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c80',
    id: 14 },
 c77:
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c77',
    id: 7 },
 c78:
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c78',
    id: 4 },
 c79:
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c79',
    id: 9 },
 c80:
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c80',
    id: 14 },
 c81:
  ModelBase {
    attributes: [Object],
    _previousAttributes: [Object],
    changed: {},
    relations: {},
    cid: 'c81',
    id: 10 } },
 relatedData:
  RelationBase {
 targetTableName: 'student',
 targetIdAttribute: 'id',
 type: 'hasMany',
 target:
  { [Function]
    super_: [Function: Events],
    extend: [Function: extend],
    extended: [Function: extended],
    __super__: [Object],
    NotFoundError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
    NoRowsUpdatedError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
    NoRowsDeletedError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
    forge: [Function: forge],
    collection: [Function: collection],
    count: [Function: count],
    fetchAll: [Function: fetchAll],
    where: [Function],
    query: [Function] },
 foreignKey: 'classroom_id',
 foreignKeyTarget: undefined,
 parentId: 6,
 parentTableName: 'classroom',
 parentIdAttribute: 'id',
 parentAttributes:
  { id: 6,
    created_at: 2018-04-24T22:23:34.819Z,
    updated_at: 2018-04-24T22:23:34.819Z,
    name: ' Classroom 1' },
 parentFk: 6 } }
```

So I'm not sure how to make this work

Comment: Everything seems to be working as intended. What is it that makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: I found the problem.  Instead of saying - classroom.models.map                I needed to say students.map and return student.attributes not studentList.attributes

Comment: Did you know you could just call `classroom.toJSON()` to get the same result? No need to use map. You usually never need to access `model.attributes` directly.